# Issues adding voucher code to configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to add a 5% discount code to a configurable product that has alot of elements in it, it seems as though this won't work as normal becuase it is configurable even though I have the category selected. Any ideas on how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a discount based on category, I believe you need to assign each of the associated simple products of the configurable to the same category. A configurable product is really a virtual product; it's the simple products that actually receive the discount.

Alternatively, you could use an "or" condition in your discount and add the individual SKUs of any associated simple products if you don't want them assigned to the same category.